# Set arbitrary value of WPF ComboBox which bound to dictionary

Tags: wpf, combobox, binding

I have the editable ComboBox that using binding to dictionary:

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True" ItemsSource="{Binding MyDict}" DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedValuePath="Value" SelectedValue="{Binding MyProp}" />
```

Sometimes I need set in code to property *MyProp* some different value, that is not presented in the dictionary. In such situation ComboBox is not dispalay the value.

What should I do to ComboBox be able to display arbitrary value in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ComboBox` cannot select arbitrary values. It can only select a value or item that is present in its `Items` or `ItemsSource` collection.

So you must add an entry to `MyDict` before you can select it. You may set the `Text` property of the `ComboBox` to a random `string`, but this won't select any item and set the `MyProp` property.

Comment: Ok, it's an idea! I just add to ComboBox *Text={Binding MyProp, Converter={StaticResource str2intConverter}}* and it's exactly what I need. Here *str2intConverter* is a simple converter, that converts string to integer and back, and if passed string is empty, converter returns Null. In such case, property is set correctly by the input text. And also displayed value is the same as was set code behind. Thank you!

Comment: Almost forget: dictionary keeps integer values, that's why converter is string to integer.